# Oracle SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I am doing a simple insert and am stumped, I'm new to oracle and unsure of what the issue is. I don't have the table structure so I am guessing that most of the fields are character except the dates.

Anyway here is my query, can anyone find the issue?

```
INSERT INTO PHANTOM_BOXES (CARRIER_CODE,CARRIER_TRACKING_NO,SENT_DATE,SEND_COST,
  RECEIVED_DATE,REC_COST, COMMENTS,SHIPPING_TECH,RECEIVING_TECH) 
VALUES ('1','11',TO_DATE('2016-02-04','YYYY-MM-DD'),'1',
 TO_DATE('2016-02-04','YYYY-MM-DD'),'1','1','26437','0') 
WHERE BOX_NO = '6738'
```

Comment: An `INSERT` has no `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

NO where dude.what is ther where for.

```
INSERT INTO PHANTOM_BOXES (CARRIER_CODE,CARRIER_TRACKING_NO,SENT_DATE,SEND_COST,
 RECEIVED_DATE,REC_COST, COMMENTS,SHIPPING_TECH,RECEIVING_TECH,BOX_NO) 
VALUES ('1','11',TO_DATE('2016-02-04','YYYY-MM-DD'),'1',
 TO_DATE('2016-02-04','YYYY-MM-DD'),'1','1','26437','0','6738')
```

Comment: Gah so obvious in hindsight, ty

Answer (score 1):

> WHERE BOX_NO = '6738'

**INSERT** statement cannot have a **WHERE** clause, makes no sense.

Simply do `INSERT INTO..VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO PHANTOM_BOXES (CARRIER_CODE,CARRIER_TRACKING_NO,SENT_DATE,SEND_COST,
  RECEIVED_DATE,REC_COST, COMMENTS,SHIPPING_TECH,RECEIVING_TECH) 
VALUES ('1','11',TO_DATE('2016-02-04','YYYY-MM-DD'),'1',
 TO_DATE('2016-02-04','YYYY-MM-DD'),'1','1','26437','0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Where Clause is used for filter and applying condition Rows which were already present in Table.

Seems you are trying to update the values for WHERE BOX_NO = '6738'
For this you have to use Update Statement

```
Update PHANTOM_BOXES 
Set     CARRIER_CODE='1',
CARRIER_TRACKING_NO='11',
SENT_DATE=TO_DATE('2016-02-04','YYYY-MM-DD'),
SEND_COST='1',
RECEIVED_DATE=TO_DATE('2016-02-04','YYYY-MM-DD'),
REC_COST='1',
COMMENTS,SHIPPING_TECH='26437',
RECEIVING_TECH='0';
```